# What is the discriminant of equation, ax^3 - bx + c

Tags: discriminant

Need to find parameters for variables 'a' 'b' 'c' that lead to the graph possessing exactly 2 x axis intercepts and for that I need the discriminant of this equation

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Discriminant?

Comment: I assume that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ (you don't say it). In this case, a third degree equation cannot have "just" 2 real roots : if it has 2 real roots, the third root is also real ! The reason : because complex roots come by pairs : if you have a complex root, the complex conjugate of this root is also a root.

Comment: @JeanMarie - but two of three real roots could be the same.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair You are right...

Comment: This discriminant is in fact classical once you have factored out  $a$ : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1732130/305862)